# Mouse double-click isn't working in Gnome

Tags: debian, gnome, mouse, gui

My mouse has no hardware problem and I have checked it on my other system.

In my Debian *v9.3* Gnome *v3.22.2* system double-click doesn't work in *File Manager*, *LibreOffice*, every place so far where I am used to it.

When I double click on the text, it will not be selected.

When I double click on the folder, the folder will not open. I have to right-click once, then select *Open* from the list.

From the beginning it was not like this, it's been three days that I've faced this problem.

I do not remember changing any particular settings manually.

How do I re-enable double click?

---

I'm running, (as reported by [`neofetch`](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch)):

```
Debian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch) 
x86_64 with Gnome 3.22.2 (desktop environment)
ThinkPad Edge E540
Kernel: 4.9.0-5-amd64
Packages: 2481
Shell: bash 4.4.12
DE: GNOME
WM: GNOME Shell
Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
CPU: Intel i5-4300M (4) @ 3.3GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M
Memory: 3674MB
```

Comment: Please tell up what you are expecting it to do, and what it does. I guess you are running Gnome, is this correct. (amend question, with clarification)

Comment: By FileManager I'm assuming Nautilus. I loaded Nautilus, then clicked icon far right (filing-cabinet icon; I have my close|min|max buttons top left so position may differ for you).  Clicking Preferences, then "behavior" there is a "open action" which has single-click, double-click & other options. Have a look (sorry I'm not a gnome user so this may not be what you want)

Comment: Unfortunately this question likely too vague to yield useful answers. Any details details and context you could narrow down possible causes would be helpful, e.g. what desktop environment are you using, have you have you ruled out a faulty mouse, have you recently changed any settings related to the mouse?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install neofetch`, then run `neofetch --stdout | grep 'DE:\|WM:'` and report what that shows.

Comment: @agc
I completed the question with the requested information
If any other information is needed, guide me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes double-click can seem broken if the double-click speed is (somehow) set too fast.  If the second click is too long after the first, the *GUI* will get two separate *single* clicks, not a double-click.

1. Go to: *Applications › System Tools › Settings › Universal Access*.

   [image]
2. Scroll to the bottom.

   [image]

   Adjust the slider at *Pointing & Clicking > Double-Click Delay*.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for it under Mouse & Touchpad settings and it was not there!!